# Disconnect lid switch Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 22.04, lenovo, bios, lid

I have a lot of problems with the lid switch events with my laptop (lenovo legion slim 5, Ubuntu 22.04.4).

So I would like to know if there is a way to completely disconnect the lid switch and make it not trigger anything in linux.

I tried to follow the instructions of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706471/linux-cli-disable-sleep-when-laptop-lid-closed) but I don't have `LID0` in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. Here is what I obtain if I do `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP5      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.1
GPP6      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.2
GP11      S4    *disabled
SWUS      S4    *disabled
GP12      S4    *disabled
SWUS      S4    *disabled
XHC0      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:06:00.3
XHC1      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:06:00.4
XHC2      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:08:00.0
NHI0      S4    *disabled 
XHC3      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.3
NHI1      S4    *disabled
XHC4      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.4
```

Can someone help me disable the lid switch?

Comment: Install 'tweaks" it has the options you want.

Comment: Hi, I installed it but it doesn't really completely disconnect the switch. My computer is still reacting to it.